# Find the dimension of a spanning group over $\mathbb Z_5$

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear space is spanned by $A=\{(1,2,1,2), (2,3,1,4), (3,1,2,1)\}$ in $\mathbb Z^4_5$ over $\mathbb Z_5$. I need to find the dimension of the space.
What I did was checking whether the vectors are linearly dependent. Since they don't, I'd concluded that $dimA=3$.
Something feels wrong here, but I can't tell what. Any help?

Comment: Gauss elimination.

Comment: @Wuestenfux that led to a matrix of rank 3

Comment: Then your done. There are three independent vectors spanning the subspace.

Comment: @Wuestenfux thanks a lot!

Comment: yup, I also seem to find that the $3$ vectors are linearly independent; hence $\dim \text{span}(A) = 3$. So, as long as you're able to justify carefully why the vectors are linearly independent over the field $\Bbb{Z}_5$, you're good!